# Unable to remove marker from google map by using setMap(null) without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is my code, When i am calling removeMarkers(), it's not removing the markers.

```
function receiver(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

var json = JSON.parse(data);

  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var lat = json[i]["lat"];
    var lng = json[i]["lng"]; 
    // push object into features array
    features.push({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng) });
  }

     features.forEach(function(feature) {
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    //icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                    map: map
                });
            }); 
            gmarkers.push(marker1); 
}

function removeMarkers(){

    for(i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++){
        gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```

This is my full code. For displaying places(church) that which i saved in my database along the route from origin to destination. If i changed the origin and destination i want to remove old markers and displaying new markers without refreshing the page.

css

```
 <style>
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
```

html

```
<div id="map" height="460px" width="100%"></div>
     <input type="text" id="distance" value="3" size="2">
     <input type="text" id="from" />to
     <input type="text" id="to"  />
     <input type="submit" onClick="route()" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_ key&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/routeboxer/src/RouteBoxer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

javascript

```
 <script>
        var map;
        var marker;
        var infowindow;
        var messagewindow;
        var boxpolys = null;
        var directions = null;
        var routeBoxer = null;
        var distance = null; // km
        var service = null;
        var gmarkers = [];
        var boxes = null;
        var coordinates=null;
        var features = [];
        var gmarkers = [];
    <?php
        echo "
        var lat={$lat}; 
        var lng={$lng};
        "
    ?>

      function initialize() {

        var location = {lat: 10.525956868983068, lng:76.21387481689453};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: location,
          zoom: 13
        });

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
         routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer();

  directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });
      }

function route() {

removeMarkers()
 clearBoxes();

  distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 0.1;
  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
    destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }

  directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

      var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;

      boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);

       drawBoxes(); 
      findPlaces(0);
    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });

}
function drawBoxes() {

  boxpolys = new Array(boxes.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    boxpolys[i] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      bounds: boxes[i],
      fillOpacity: 0,
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeColor: '#000000',
      strokeWeight: 0,
      map: map
    });
  }
}

function findPlaces(searchIndex) {

  var request = {
    bounds: boxes[searchIndex],
  };

  coordinates = boxes[searchIndex].toString().match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g);

  $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost/church_finder/index.php/MapController/search_church",
                type:'POST',
                data:{coordinates:coordinates},
                //dataType:'json',
                 success: receiver
               });

    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
      searchIndex++;
      if (searchIndex < boxes.length)
        findPlaces(searchIndex);
    } else { 
      setTimeout("findPlaces(" + searchIndex + ")", 1000);
    }
}

function clearBoxes() {

  if (boxpolys != null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < boxpolys.length; i++) {
      boxpolys[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
  boxpolys = null;
}

function receiver(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {


var json = JSON.parse(data);
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var lat = json[i]["lat"];
    var lng = json[i]["lng"]; 
    features.push({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng) });
  }     
     features.forEach(function(feature) {
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    map: map
                });
            }); 
            gmarkers.push(marker1); 
}

function removeMarkers(){

    for(i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++){
        gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hm1zn.png)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removeMarkers(){
  features.length=0;
  if (gmarkers != []) {
        for(var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++){
        gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
    gmarkers =[];       
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added gmarkers = []; but still not removing.

Comment: if you do a console.log of gmarkers, can you see the markers? are you pushing them there correctly?

Comment: and where in your code you call the Route Function? that is the one that actually calls removeMarkers()

Comment: Sorry i updated my html section, from there i calling the route function.

Comment: When using console.log i am getting [] 
userView:216 [_.Ie]
userView:216 (2) [_.Ie, _.Ie]
userView:216 (3) [_.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie]
userView:216 (4) [_.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie]
userView:216 (5) [_.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie]
userView:216 (6) [_.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie, _.Ie]  ouput like this in console

Comment: I could recreat your code as i could in jsbin http://jsbin.com/yixineb/1/edit?html,js,output and it is removing the markers(you need to add your api key to the script). first I try a route from Thrissur to Ayyanthole, and right after I do a Route from Thrissur to Poothole.

Comment: note that I commented 2 lines that were throwing errors inside initalize (you want to check that out) but the logic in the delete of the markers is fine

Comment: Again sorry i forgot to mention <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/routeboxer/src/RouteBoxer.js" type="text/javascript"></script> above code thats why you got error in intialize. That two lines you commented is very important in my code.

Comment: If you are using those service correctly then you shouldn't have problem deleting the markers (as you can see in the jsbin, after each call to Route(), past markers are "erased" and new markers appear)

Comment: still not working for me. added one screen shot above.

Comment: updated the answer where i think could be the issue, the problem is that i cannot completely reproduce so is harder to find, hope this works

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I tried it before but still not removing.I added one image above that is the actual problem. when i choose one origin and destination it will draw the blue line and display nearby places that which i saved in my database after that i am again choosing another origin and destination it will draw blue line and display nearby place along the route but the old marker still exist there. When am doing refresh after first one it will work fine.

Comment: yes I get your problem, the route refresh correctly (as i could recreat) the issue is the markers (the features lat/lngs location where you create markers), now since the logic for deleting the markers looks good, I think the issue has to be that the markers are not correctly pushed to gmarkers

Comment: I just edited my answer, try using a for loop instead of the forEach method

Comment: i tried but, it's not displaying markers. I found problem with 'data'. I am using ajax, from there i call the function receiver and also pass the result as 'data' .console.log(data) which show coordinates when i first select origin and destination then for the second time it's showing old coordinates plus new coordinates. so i want to remove that old corrdinates from data, what should i do?

Comment: i just updated the answer, try this first before i continue troubleshooting

Comment: sorry, i updated my code as gmarkers.splice(i, 1);
return; but still not removing.

Comment: sorry i added the return by mistake...if you take it out? nothing?

Comment: is there any way to refresh map to remove markers instead of page?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.I solved my problem. I just added one line in removeMarkers(), features.length=0; it's solved my problem. I edited your answer. once again thank you.

Comment: hoped i helped you troubleshooting! nice to hear you could solved this after all the effort done.

Answer (score 0):

Your app throws loads of errors in the console and this is just a temporary fix to what you are asking for:

> change the origin and destination, I want to remove old markers and
>   displaying new markers without refreshing the page

1. call your `initialize()` function with a script tag in your HTML file. This is where you include your API key for the project:

   ```
    <script defer async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
     key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initialize">
   ```
2. Where is the `map element` passed in the `map constructor`?

Create a `div` element in your HTML to contain the map and add CSS style to it

```
#map {
height: 100%;
}

html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
}
```

This is actually in the [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial);

> Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
>   element that contains the map.

Now into your JS code...
What are you using `var service` for? `var service` is firstly declared in the global scope with a `null` value and then assigned to a `PlacesService` constructor...but `service` is not defined simply because you have not included the `places library` in your script tag:

**ADD PLACES LIBRARY IF YOU WANT TO USE PLACES API**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
 key=YOUR_API_KEY&_ADD_libraries=places_PLEASE_"></script>
```

Because `var service` cannot be run, just remove it (it actually does not do anything but adding lines in your code right now) along with the `RouteBoxer()`

**REMOVE THESE LINES - THEY ARE USELESS RIGHT NOW**

```
 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
 routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer();
```

If you do this, without refreshing the page, you clear the markers for each subsequent requests. You get loads of errors still because you have both syntax and logic bugs in your app.

[Get a BIN here](https://jsbin.com/lefikis/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer(); this is not useless, one of the main part in my code, routerBoxer helps to draw small rectangle boxes along the route. I compare the box coordinate limit with my database to fetch coordinates within the box limit from database, then displaying the coordinates in google map. Sorry i am new to google map api and javascript. Sorry for my mistakes

Comment: added one screenshot above, first selected one origin and destination and it's displays nearby saved coordinates along the route.after without refreshing i choose another destination it draws the route also shown saved coordinate along the route but old route marker is still there.

Comment: that is not the point of what I have just said. You app breaks at different points and if you use `constructors` that **cannot be used** because the libraries are not loaded correctly or are missing completely, this throw errors in the console and make the app behaving weirdly. Have you *actually** used the code in the BIN I have just sent you? Because if I go through your application trying to solve your issue and then you are completely ignoring the suggestions and come back with more examples of what is not working then...well you catch the drift do not you?

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I tried my code in BIN, It's working without any error .i updated my code above as per what you told before, except this one '<script defer async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
  key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initialize">' when adding like this, i got error   "Uncaught Qb {message: "initialize is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵    at new Qb (https://maps.googleapis.com/m…nuitIJM5A3ZLSnJYBcF1Wo&callback=initialize:151:59"}".

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.I solved my problem. I just added one line in removeMarkers(), features.length=0; it's solved my problem. once again thank you for helping me.